Оптимизация(ускорение): Pandas, Apply
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть возможность ускорить функцию pandas apply или выполнить решение по другому.
Есть DataFrame(25 000 строк) - df, который содержит наименование номенклатуры и Series(800 строк) - Group данные.
Необходимо выполнить сравнение на совпадение данных при помощи Fuzzywuzzy, df('Nomenclatura') и Series(Groups), создать новый столбец с названием группа.
Пример:
Таблица - Nomenclatura содержит наименование:
Натрий фосфат
Натрий азид
Натрий гидроокись
Соответственно группа будет Натрий.
Мое решение:
  def func1(f):
      dct = {}
      for ch in Group['Groups']:
            if fuzz.WRatio(f, ch) >= 70:
            dct[ch] = fuzz.WRatio(f, ch)
      return dct

df['ProductGroup'] = df['Nomenclatura'].apply(func1)

PS: Словарь создаю, т.к. fuzz может не все данные подтянуть корректно, для проверки информации.
Результат необходим такой:

Данное решение занимает очень большое количество времени от 5 до 10 минут в зависимости от количества строк.

Условие использование fuzzywazzy обязательное? Посмотреть бы данные, может там и без нечеткого сравнения можно, но как понять не видя данные.

К сожалению да, потому что группа выделялась из наименования товара(Т.е. сначала были разделено наименование на слова, а потом уже из этих слов выявлялась основная группа), слова написаны косовато, и не все совпадают, окончания, и т.д.

А наименования в столбце повторяются или уникальны? Если уникальны, то тут только распараллеливать как-то процесс. А вот если повторяются, то можно выкинуть дубликаты, сделать apply, а потом join/merge результата на исходный столбец. Ну или lru_cache применить поверх вызова fuzz с тем же успехом.

Дубликаты уже убрал, вот как раз после удаления дубликатов грузит 5 минут.  Спасибо за информацию, завтра попробую через lru_cache и вхождение.

Да нет, если дубликатов нет, то lru_cache не поможет. А почему для вас 5 минут - это много, вы эту операцию регулярно повторяете? Если повторяете, то кешируйте где-то результаты вызовов fuzz и повторно их потом используйте, будет очень быстро. В базе, либо в памяти

могу порекомендовать попробовать библиотеку rapidFuzz ( https://github.com/rapidfuzz/RapidFuzz )

Да, потому что приходится частенько формировать для корректировки конечного результат. Всем большое спасибо. Попробую все варианты.

@strawdog Ого, какая там разница в скорости заявлена. Надо будет попробовать при случае эту либу.
